# generating patterned vectors / sequence in r

Tags: r

I am trying to create a table of values like:

```
k   P(X=k)

0     0.1
1     0.1*(0.9)
2     0.1*(0.9)^2
3     0.1*(0.9)^3
```

That made me wonder if there were a way to generate patterned vectors in R such as:

```
1,1,1,.9
1,1.9,.9
1,.9,.9,.9
```

This is the kind of thing I am trying to produce:

```
x1 = c(1,1,1,1,.9)

x2 = c(1,1,1,.9,.9)

x3 = c(1,1,.9,.9,.9)

x4 = c(1,.9,.9,.9,.9)

vec_mult = x1*x2*x3*x4

y = rep(0.1,5)

k = 0:4

P = y * vec_mult

write.table(cbind(k,P), row.names=F, sep ="\t")

"k"     "P"

0       0.1

1       0.09

2       0.081

3       0.0729

4       0.06561
```

Comment: You can just do `0.1 * (0.9)^(0:4)`. The exponent operator is vectorized in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lign of code you are looking for is

```
.1*.9^(0:15)
```

You can exponentiate by a vector in R.

Comment: amazing; so fast an answer, and so simple

Answer (score 0):

To make your patterned vector, you just need something like:

```
make_vec <- function(x, y, n1, n2)  c(rep(x, n1), rep(y, n2)) 
list_of_vecs <- lapply(0:5, f(n) make_vec(1, 0.9, 5 - n, n))
```

But it's even easier to do your cumulative product.  Just do

```
0.1 * .9^(0:5)
```